# Dynamics crm set status code with custom code

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

Inside Dynamics CRM Online 2016 I have added Custom status code which has value of 814 410 000 and I am trying to set it programatically inside the application. Unfortunately I keep on getting error msg that this value is not valid for CampaignState.Inactive. All changes are published. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide your code and screenshot of form with your custom status code (I'm interested in parent state code for this status code).

Comment: If you are attempting to set the attribute via C#, you should set it in the following way: `new OptionSetValue((int)CampaignState.Inactive));`